# Spring Autowire Issue with JavaConfig, getBean returns null (no exceptions)

Tags: spring

Using Spring 4.0.3.RELEASE...

I've been converting our use of Spring XML-based config to JavaConfig, and I've hit an issue that I do not understand.  Everything works fine when run on a developer's machine (Windows 7 and 8), but fails when run on the build server (Ubuntu) - as part of the build we have unit tests that kick off, and when the unit tests run on the build server they all fail.  The symptom is that the application context getBean("name") returns null.  Here is how things are set up:

```
package com.x.common;

public class BeanFactory {
    private static ApplicationContext _context;

    static {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        if (ctx.getEnvironment().getActiveProfiles().length == 0) {
            ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("prod");
        }

        ctx.scan("com.x.common.config");
        ctx.refresh();

        _context = ctx;
    }

    public static Object get(String name) {
        return _context.getBean(name);
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.x.common.config;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Autowired ILogger logger;
    @Bean public ILogger logger() {
        return logger;
    }
}

@Configuration
@Profile("prod")
public class ProdConfig {
    @Bean public ILogger logger() {
        return new ConsoleLogger("prod");
    }
}
```

I have a unit test that's basically just

```
ILogger logger = (ILogger)BeanFactory.get("logger");
assertNotNull("Logger is null", logger);
```

When the unit test executes on a developer machine, either as part of the build or run individually in Eclipse, logger is an object of type ConsoleLogger.  But when the unit test executes on the build machine (invoked by Jenkins), logger is null and no exceptions are thrown.  A couple of people here have looked at it, but none of us are Spring masters (in fact I just started using Spring a couple of weeks ago), and we can't figure out what the problem is.  When the unit tests first start a number of things get logged to the console (Spring telling us it found AppConfig and it is overwriting the return values with those of ProdConfig), and the print outs look the same when run locally and when run on the build machine.  Nothing obvious stands out as to what the problem might be.

Thing worked fine with the XML config files, but we weren't using Autowire with those.

Comment: Are you sure you correctly have `"prod"` in the `@Profile` and `setActiveProfile`? Your example works fine for me.

Comment: For testing, add other `static` method to retrieve all bean names, to check profiles, etc. Or go to debug mode.